# Laravel. Attempt to read property on null with accesor

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-filament

In default way Filament save image as a path/file.name in model column.

I need to teach it to save image in other table files, and in model column save file_id.

I did this. But standard filament component FileUpload doesn't display saved image.

I'm trying to put image path for Filament FileUpload component by accessor:

```
public function getFileAttribute($value)
{
    $file = File::find((int) $value);

    $path = (string) $file->path;

    // dd($path);

    return $path;
}
```

I am getting an error:

> Attempt to read property "path" on null

But if I uncomment `dd($path)`, I see the correct path. Can you help me? I don't understand why I am getting this error.

##### Guide Model

```php
class Guide extends Model
{
    // ...

    protected $with = ['file'];

    protected $fillable = [
        'file',
        // ...
    ];

    protected $appends = [
        'file',
    ];

    // ...

    public function file(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(File::class);
    }

    // ...

    public function getFileAttribute($value)
    {
        $file = File::find((int) $value);

        $path = (string) $file->path;

        // dd($path);

        return $path;
    }

    public function setFileAttribute($value)
    {
        $file = new File;
        $file->path = $value;
        $file->save();

        $this->attributes['file'] = (string) $file->id;
    }

    // ...
}
```

**GuideResource**:

```php
class GuideResource extends Resource
{
    protected static ?string $model = Guide::class;

    protected static ?string $navigationIcon = 'heroicon-o-collection';

    public static function form(Form $form): Form
    {
        return $form->schema([
            Forms\Components\TextInput::make('title')->required(),
            Forms\Components\TextInput::make('description')->required(),
            Forms\Components\FileUpload::make('file')->directory('guide'),
            Checkbox::make('active'),
        ]);
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: _"Attempt to read property "path" on null. But if i uncomment dd($b) i see correct path"_ This doesn't seem possible. What do you get if you `var_dump($file);`?

Comment: `::find(...)` can return `null`, and `null->path` is not valid code. You need to debug what `$value` is and why it is returning `null`, and handle it (i.e. return `$file->path ?? null`, etc.)

Comment: Alex,
var_dump print object(App\Models\File)
where i can see "path" i need in attributes and in original arrays
...
["attributes":protected]=> array(9) { ["id"]=> int(3) ["type"]=> NULL ["size"]=> NULL ["disk"]=> NULL ["path"]=> string(86) "guide/u03QM7hBOqmXGPrq1yKGEErh8bqHny-metaU2Ny0LLQsNC_0YvQstCw0L_Ri2VlbnNob3QucG5n-.png"
...

Comment: Tim,
i can handle this by $b = (string)$file?->path;
but i can't understand reasons for this error.

Comment: What are you not understanding? `::find()` returns `null` if the value provided doesn't match an `id` in your database. You are currently doing nothing to handle that scenario, and this is triggering an error when you end up with `null->path`. `$file?->path` is "null-safe" and handles that.

Comment: If `$file` contains an object, then either this code is in a loop and you're getting the error on a different iteration than you're getting the non-empty path, or the error is not being generated by the line you think it is.

Answer (score -1):

The reason that you do see a path when using `dd()` is likely due to the function being called multiple times.

A couple things can be changed in your code such as passing an instance of `File` into the function, which ensures that this function will always get an instance of the model, however here is a little snippet that can help you debug it yourself.

```
public function getFileAttribute((int) $value)
{
    $file = File::find($value);

    if (!$file) {
        dd($value, $file);
    }

    $path = (string) $file->path;

    // dd($path);

    return $path;
}
```

You will see that `$file` will be `null` in the dump, however it will also dump the passed `$value` for you to help debug the problem.

This is in no-way a solution to your problem but simply a little helping snippet to figure out the issue as there isn't enough code to correctly see why this is happening.